# Where can I have discussion about code/libraries?

Tags: discussion, design

I don't have a question about code. I want to talk about the pros/cons about a design or library and hear the opinion of others. Discussions are off topic on Programmers.SE so my question is

Where can programmers have discussion about code and libraries?

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: for pros/cons design related. This is the right place. Shoot your question :)

Comment: @DemianBrecht How do you figure? Questions on Code Review are still expected to include code.

Comment: @AnnaLear: My bad, I figured that you might be able to get a review on an algorithm on code review.

Comment: Design/algorithm questions are okay here. Stuff like "let's discuss a library" or "what's your opinion" isn't really SE material in general. [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21) could work, though. (cc @DemianBrecht)

Answer (score 7):

No Stack Exchange site is suitable for holding a discussion, but if you have specific and answerable questions about architecture, design, and testing, those are more than welcome here on Programmers. In fact, those conceptual questions are why this site exists.

Answer (score 4):

I might be missing something because no one mentioned the obvious option, but here it goes:

How about [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)?

The language specific [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) on Stack Overflow would be ideal, as would be our [own chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/programmers). And you can even create your own chat room.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Programmers blog.  If you want to write a blog post on the design of an open source project that is of somewhat general interest (so, not the library you are thinking about writing) then it might get approved (odds would rise dramatically the more of the work you were willing to do yourself).

If you wrote a good enough original article you might attract people to add to it.  This would be somewhat like a discussion, though more work and ultimately of higher quality.